# pass fixture to test class in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Consider the following pseudocode demonstrating my question:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def param1():
    # return smth
    yield "wilma"


@pytest.fixture
def param2():
    # return smth
    yield "fred"


@pytest.fixture
def bar(param1, param2):
    #do smth
    return [Bar(param1, param2), Bar(param1, param2)]


@pytest.fixture
def first_bar(bar):
    return bar[0]


class Test_first_bar:

    # FIXME: how do I do that?
    #def setup_smth???(self, first_bar):
    #    self.bar = first_bar


    def test_first_bar_has_wilma(self):
        # some meaningful check number 1
        assert self.bar.wilma == "wilma"


    def test_first_bar_some_other_check(self):
        # some meaningful check number 2
        assert self.bar.fred == "fred"
```

Basically I want to pass `first_bar` fixture to my `Test_first_bar` class in order to reuse that object in all its test methods. How should I go about dealing with such situation?

Python 3, if that matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, you can define your fixture as `autouse`. Which would be called automatically for all the tests of your class. Here, I cant understand what is `[Bar(param1, param2), Bar(param1, param2)]`. Well, that's not the point, if rest of the code is working fine than you can try the below solution. I have replaced the code with static variables to verify if it's working or not and it's working fine at my end.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def param1():
    # return smth
    yield "wilma"


@pytest.fixture
def param2():
    # return smth
    yield "fred"


@pytest.fixture
def bar(param1, param2):
    # do smth
    return [Bar(param1, param2), Bar(param1, param2)]


@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def first_bar(bar, request):
    request.instance.bar = bar[0]

class Test_first_bar:

    def test_first_bar_has_wilma(self,request):
        print request.instance.bar

    def test_first_bar_some_other_check(self,request):
        print request.instance.bar
```

And if you do not want to make fixture as `autouse`, than you can call it before your test. Like,

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def param1():
    # return smth
    yield "wilma"


@pytest.fixture
def param2():
    # return smth
    yield "fred"


@pytest.fixture
def bar(param1, param2):
    # do smth
    return [Bar(param1, param2), Bar(param1, param2)]


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def first_bar(bar, request):
    request.instance.bar = bar[0]

class Test_first_bar:

    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("first_bar")
    def test_first_bar_has_wilma(self,request):
        print request.instance.bar

    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("first_bar")
    def test_first_bar_some_other_check(self,request):
        print request.instance.bar
```

Comment: I got error 
> E                   TypeError: test_first_bar_has_wilma() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Answer (score 1):

Just add `@pytest.mark.usefixtures` to your test class:

```py
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("first_bar")
class Test_first_bar:
    def test_first_bar_has_wilma(self):
```

Works in pytest 7.4.2

Comment: this works alright... now how can one access this `first_bar` fixture in the methods of the class it was passed to... i have looked into the attributes of the class and could see a pytestmark attribute which contains the passed in fixture as a string.. but what i actually want is the fixture data (returned value) as i would get when i am passing the fixture in as a method argument of the test class