# How to get fixture value from test method declared within a unittest TestCase class?

Tags: pytest, fixtures, test-class

My google search [here](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1869&bih=981&sxsrf=ACYBGNQYvOu356N0VDdLsFehcgcvNYIwRg%3A1581172127643&ei=n8U-XvjiJtay9QOb1LSwCw&q=pytest%20%2B%20usefixtures&oq=pytest%20%2B%20usefixtures&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30l10.24398.24398..24800...0.1..0.100.100.0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.AC4IUcPCz2w&ved=0ahUKEwi4rvyXlcLnAhVWWX0KHRsqDbY4FBDh1QMICw&uact=5) only shows this most-related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44897981/248616); though I can only have [my code](https://github.com/namgivu/demo-pytest-fixture/commit/0977cf298b61be0305f26bec8ad11edccd6e9b7a) working for [test method](https://github.com/namgivu/demo-pytest-fixture/commit/0977cf298b61be0305f26bec8ad11edccd6e9b7a#diff-2c6b3f680e158ff30b574ce53c80fe88R11) BUT [NOT with unittest TestCase class method](https://github.com/namgivu/demo-pytest-fixture/commit/0977cf298b61be0305f26bec8ad11edccd6e9b7a#diff-2c6b3f680e158ff30b574ce53c80fe88R11).

My question is how to get fixture value from test method declared within a unittest TestCase class?

I quote the code snippet here

```
import pytest
from unittest import TestCase


@pytest.fixture()
def fx_return_value():
    yield 'some returned value'


@pytest.mark.usefixtures(fx_return_value.__name__)
def test0(fx_return_value):
    print(fx_return_value)


class Test1(TestCase):
    @pytest.mark.usefixtures(fx_return_value.__name__)
    def test1(self, fx_return_value):  #TODO Error here > TypeError: test1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fx_return_value'
        print(fx_return_value)
```

Comment: Pytest to run unittest.

Comment: What test class tyoe should I use?

Comment: Okie I will try again

Comment: Got it working for test class @MrBeanBremen - please post your comment to use plain class instead of unittest.TestCase as answer so as to get accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pytest` and `unittest` are separate test frameworks and are not intended to be mixed. You can use test classes in `pytest` alongside with `setup` and `teardown` methods without the need of a specific base class.

So to fix your problem you just have to remove the `unittest.TestCase` base from your test class.

*Edit:*
The statement about not mixing `pytest` and `unittest` may be a bit misleading. For clarification: you can always run `unittest` tests using `pytest`, just not the other way around.
`Pytest` is specifically written with compatibility to `unittest` (and `nosetest`) in mind, maing the conversion to `pytest` easier.
In contrast, `unittest` cannot know about `pytest`, so `pytest` features like fixtures cannot be used in `unittest`.